# Postman OAuth 2.0 "request url is empty" error even though successful authentication

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, oauth-2.0, postman

I authenticate using OAuth 2.0 authorization code workflow successfully and get redirected back to Postman. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) is more information on the Azure DevOps REST API I am trying to do.

In the console, I get an error: `request URL is empty`

I **do not** see the authorization code in the response for me to parse, but if I expand the error message and look in the Request Body > code, my authorization code is there!

I am able to use the authorization code to successfully obtain an Access Token as well.

Steps to reproduce error:

1. I set all of the values in the OAuth 2.0 form
2. I click Get New Access Token
3. I get redirected to my browser to accept
4. I get a successful authentication & get redirected back to Postman
5. I get the Authorization code in the request body of a console error (I also get the auth code in the URL after authenticating)

On step #5, **I expect** to get redirected back to Postman **successfully** with the authorization code in the body of the message.

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT: The solution below works for the Azure API with a scope of https://graph.microsoft.com. If the scope is https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com (which is what I'm using), the solution will not work oddly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try my steps to get access token with `OAuth 2.0` in Postman.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Callback URL**: the `Redirect URI` in Application > Authentication. It is required. Don't select *Authorize using browser*.

**Auth URL**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

**Access Token URL**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

[image]

[image]

For more information, you could refer to the [blog](https://liupeirong.github.io/postmanAzureFunctions/) which uses oauth2 v1.0.

Comment: Hi Pamela, it seems like the difference between your POST request and mine is that you are passing in client_secret & the access_token_url. For authorization_code, I "thought" you didn't need those? Could you elaborate on why the client_secret and the access_token_url would be needed here, please?

Comment: I pass in `client_secret` because it is required for web apps and web APIs, which have the ability to store the client_secret securely on the server side, doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-client_secret). `access_token_url` is needed see the [document](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#authorization-code) about Postman.

Comment: Will this still work if I don't have an app? I'd like Postman to handle this entirely if possible

Comment: If it is a native app or single page app, you could skip client_secret.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Pamela. I've made an edit to my post regarding your solution. It works for the Azure API with a scope of https://graph.microsoft.com. If the scope is https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com (which is what I'm using), the solution will not work oddly enough.